# How to passed selected list in stored procedure using Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I can get the `id` of selected list using javascript. Like this.

```
<script>
   function showCategoryOptions(s)
   {
    console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value);
   }
</script>
```

But I'm thinking how can I passed the value of the selected list in my stored procedure? How can I make a variable to get the value of selected list and passed it into my stored procedure? For I'm able to get the values.

SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category_type =  p_SelectedItem;
```

Here when I'm gonna equal the selected item in list. But still don't have any idea how will do this. Any help would appreciated!

Controller:

```
public function getDocuments()
{
  $resultCategory = DB::table('categories')->get();

  $myResult = DB::select('call getCategoryIdStoredProc(?)',array ($category));      

  return view ('document.create')with('resultCategory', $resultCategory);
}
```

I passed an array here in `$myResult` but unfortunately it gives me a error.

> Undefined variable: category

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category_type');
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('categories');
}
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/create',
[
'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@getDocuments',
'as' => 'document.create',
'middleware' => 'auth',
]);
```

Form:

```
<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "category" class = "control-label">Category:</label>
    <select onChange = "showCategoryOptions(this)" name = "category" class = "form-control">

            @foreach ($resultCategory as $categoryList)
            <option value = "{{ $categoryList->id }}">{{ $categoryList->category_type }}</option>
            @endforeach

    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Where u defined $category ? I dont see it.

Comment: @rad11 In my `$myResult` I'm not sure if I passed the correct object in the array.

Comment: In your function getDocuments u dont defined variable $category and you did not convey this variable parameter so that why u got this error

Comment: Oh I see. I already passed my variable $category. But is says `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController::getDocuments()`

Comment: Show route for this method and update your question what u got know

Comment: @rad11 I updated my post. Can you please see it if I missed something.